# Upload data (pictures, videos etc.)on Heroku

Tags: android, file-upload, heroku

I want to upload pictures and videos captured to Heroku server using my android app. I have searched a lot but cant find solution. Can Anyone tell me how can I do that?At least give me a startup Please help I want it to get going. I am stuck cant find anything. Using buttons in my app i want to upload different things.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need somewhere to store these photos (like amazon s3) and a library to deliver them there from heroku (carrier wave or paper clip Gems if using ruby on rails).

That's it for the server side.

Comment: Can you give some links how would I do that using eclipse like you can say what java coding would be. Thanks

Comment: Is this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java  what i am looking for??? Remember In my android app within button click listener I want to do this uploading.